# Solving this Bernouli's ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The question is to solve this $DE$:

$$(E):y'-\frac{1}{x}y^2+(2+\frac{1}{x})y=x+2$$

As a hint, the particular solution was given, $u(x)=x$ is a solution to this $D.E$.

When trying to solve the homogeneous $D.E$

$$(H): y'-\frac{1}{x}y^2+(2+\frac{1}{x})y=0$$
$$(H): \frac{y'}{y^2}+(2+\frac{1}{x})\frac{1}{y}=\frac{1}{x}$$

by doing the known substitution $u=y^{-1} \implies u'=-y^{-2}y'$ we get to a first order $ODE$ :

$(E_1): v'-(2+\frac{1}{x})v=-\frac{1}{x}$

which then we solve the homogenous equation: $v'-(2+\frac{1}{x})v=0 $

We find $v_h(x)=Ce^{2x}x \implies v'_h(x)=C'e^{2x}x+C(2e^{2x}x+e^{2x})$

. By the method of constant variation, we find the $v_p$, but this is where i'm having trouble, After substituing in $(E_1)$, I get:

$C'e^{2x}x+C(2e^{2x}x+e^{2x})+(2+\frac{1}{x}) Ce^{2x}x=-\frac{1}{x} \implies C'=-\frac{e^{-2x}}{x^2}$, but integrating this is not easy (i think), after plugging it into online integral calculators, It seems that it's not expressible in elementary functions.

So maybe the way i'm approaching this is wrong from the start? Any help is appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you are supposed to use $y=z+x$ as a susbstitution

Then you get the Bernouilli's equation

$$z'+\frac zx=\frac {z^2}{x}$$
$$xz'+ z=\frac {x^2z^2}{x^2}$$
$$(xz)'=\frac {(xz)^2}{x^2}$$
$$\int \frac {dxz}{(xz)^2}=\int \frac {dx}{x^2}$$
$$z(x)=\frac {1}{Kx+1}$$
$$\boxed{y(x)=x+\frac {1}{Kx+1}}$$

I don't think you made a mistake with the variation of constant
I didn't find any mistake.
..Sometimes it happens that the integral can't be evaluated with elementary functions.

---

***Edit***

Claude's answer is the same you end with the same solution whether you start with $y_p=x$ or $y_p=x+1$...

$$y=x+1-\frac x{x+c_1}$$
$$y=x+\frac {x+c_1}{x+c_1}-\frac x{x+c_1}$$
$$y=x+\frac {x+c_1-x}{x+c_1}$$
$$y=x+\frac {c_1}{x+c_1}$$
$$y=x+\frac {1}{x/c_1+1}$$
$$y=x+\frac {1}{Kx+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for your reply, so the way to go when dealing with a bernouli's eq. with a non-zero second term is to use the substitution $y=u+z$? where $u$ is a particular solution?

Comment: @MarioSOUPER thats the substitution used for the Riccati equation so then you get the Bernouilli equation...the particular solution is x not u...u is the other part of the solution. So use the substitution $y=u+x$

Comment: yes in this case it's $x$, but in general it's $y=z+u$ where $u$ is the particular solution?

Comment: Yes thats the classical substitution when a particular solution is known for the Riccatti's equation ( the equation you have)..@MarioSOUPER

Comment: Okay thanks, i wonder why the guy below had a different result though..

Comment: @MarioSOUPER Claude has the same solution ...finish simplifying his solution it's the same as mine...We started with different particular solution..ma with $y_p=x$ and Claude with $y_p=x+$ but we both ended with the same result. I can prove it easily that both answers are equivalents

Comment: @MarioSOUPER I added some lines that shows that both answers are the same even the particular solution chosen was different...We end with the same answer

Comment: of course it is, silly me, it's just $y=x+\frac{1}{\frac{1}{c_1}(x+c_1)}$

Comment: anyway, thanks, i completly forgot about Riccati equations lol, thanks for your help again.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER it's the same answer written differently...but still same answer and Wolfram alpha give the same answer too  ...You are welcome if that helped you

Comment: I get it, thank you:).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the hint is not totally correct.

Assuming that $u(x)=x+c$ is a particular solution of the equation
$$y'-\frac{1}{x}y^2+(2+\frac{1}{x})y=x+2 \implies \frac{(c-1) c}{x}=0$$ So, $c=0$ and $c=1$ are solutions.

Using $y=x\color{red}{+1}+\frac 1z$ leads to $$xz'+z+1=0\implies z=-1+\frac {c_1} x$$ and then
$$y=x+1-\frac x{x+c_1}$$ seems to be the solution.

Comment: But since $c=0$ is a solution too, we can use $u(x)=x$ right?.

Comment: @MarioSOUPER. For sure ! In fact, I came with that after considering the solution of  $y'-\frac{1}{x}y^2+(2+\frac{1}{x})y=0$ which is quite unpleasant.